Reading parquet takes too long in parquet-java
I am using parquet-hadoop to read a Snappy-compressed parquet file. However, I discovered that the reading time is quadratic to the file size, and it is unacceptably long.
The following is the code I am using.
try (ParquetFileReader reader = ParquetFileReader.open(file, ParquetReadOptions.builder().build())) {
            ...
            MessageType schema = reader.getFileMetaData().getSchema();
            GroupRecordConverter converter = new GroupRecordConverter(schema);
            PageReadStore pageReadStore = reader.readNextRowGroup();
            MessageColumnIO columnIo = new ColumnIOFactory().getColumnIO(schema);
            RecordReader<Group> recordReader = columnIo.getRecordReader(pageReadStore, converter);

The getRecordReader step takes ~30 seconds for a 32MB parquet file, quadrupling if the file size doubles.
How could I read the file faster?
I am using parquet-hadoop 1.13.1 from parquet-java.

When I started playing with Parquet in Java I had a similar issue.
Review your project dependencies and include a logging library.
From what I remember, I was debugging the code and I found that in absence of it, internally the log level was debug, and executed the log logic, without printing it, consuming a lot of time.
